# Why is it error when my framework contains .framework file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

My project uses cocoapods to manager frameworks. The `podfile` contains the command line

```
 use_frameworks!
```

One of my framework `core` depends on another framework `UMCCommon`. So `core` framework's podspec file has command line

```
 s.dependency 'UMCCommon'
```

But the `UMCCommon` have a `UMCCommen.framework` file. Then I get an error likes below:
[image]

If I add the line

```
s.static_framework = true
```

in `core` framework another error will appear:

[image]

If import the `UMCCommon` in `podfile`:

```
pod 'UMCCommon'
```

it will be successful. And the `UMCCommon` catalogue likes below:
[image]

But I need import `UMCCommon` in `core` rather than import it in project `podfile`. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add `UMCCommon.framework` framework file you can go with `s.vendored_frameworks = 'PATH_TO_FRAMEWORK'`. Don't remove `s.static_framework = true` line when you do this. I'd recommend checking out [cocoapods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#group_file_patterns) for other available options.

Comment: How can I write the `PATH_TO_FRAMEWORK `.

Comment: If you store your .framework file in a `Frameworks` folder next to your `Core.xcodeproj` file then the path would be `Frameworks/UMCCommon.framework`

Comment: You can also add multiple static libraries by using `,`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, I completely understand your question. Do you get this error when you're trying to submit Core framework to Cocoapods? Do you get it during pod validation?

If yes, please, make sure that Core pod file contains this:

```
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'UMCCommon'
```

And Core podspec file should contain the next lines:

```
  s.static_framework = true
  s.dependency 'UMCCommon'
  s.vendored_frameworks = "UMCCommen.framework"
```

Comment: It's still have the error `The 'mytarget' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (core)`